# Error booleano palabra palindroma en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, booleano

alguno me podria dar una explicacion sobre por que no funciona este software de reocnocimiento de palabras Palindromas en Python?

```
def palindromo(cadena):

      num_letras = len(cadena) - 1       # te da el numero da caracteres -1
      for i in range(len(cadena) // 2):  # repite el loop 2 veces

        if cadena[i] != cadena[num_letras]:  # si la pimera y ultima letra != entoces la funcion es falsa(0!=3) 
                                             # si la segunda y la ultima letra != la funcion es falsa (1 != 3) 

          return False                       #si se cumple la condicion enntonces la funcion es falsa
        else:                                #de lo contrario:
          num_letras = num_letras - 1        #le restas 1 a num_letras(por que?) 

      return True                            #esto devuelve toda la funcion como verdadera


    palabra = "abba"                 
    if palindromo(palabra):
      print ("es palindromo")
    else:
      print ("no es palindromo")
```

Esta es la linea(cuarta linea) que no comprendo totalmente:

```
 if cadena[i] != cadena[num_letras]:
```

Si no me equivoco este if me dice que revisa **0 != 3 y 1 != 3** cierto? Entonces por que no funciona...
***Mi pregunta especifica es si lo unico que hace el if es esto ***
por ejemplo:

palabra = abba:

a != a , b != a

si se cumple la condicion la palabra no es palindromo

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de probar tu código y funciona perfectamente, me parece que lo has de tener mal identado, intenta copiando el código que escribo aquí, está identado correctamente:

```
def palindromo(cadena):

    num_letras = len(cadena) - 1       # te da el numero da caracteres -1
    for i in range(len(cadena) // 2):  # repite el loop 2 veces

        if cadena[i] != cadena[num_letras]:  # si la pimera y ultima letra != entoces la funcion es falsa(0!=3) 
                                             # si la segunda y la ultima letra != la funcion es falsa (1 != 3) 

            return False                       #si se cumple la condicion enntonces la funcion es falsa
        else:                                #de lo contrario:
            num_letras = num_letras - 1        #le restas 1 a num_letras(por que?) 

    return True                            #esto devuelve toda la funcion como verdadera

palabra = "anitalavalatina"
if palindromo(palabra):
    print ("es palindromo")
else:
    print ("no es palindromo")
```

Con respecto a la cuarta línea que mencionas y a tu pregunta especifica, el `if` simplemente compara 2 cosas en ese caso 2 caracteres y pregunta, son diferentes, si lo son va a entrar al `return False` lo que significa que no fue un palíndromo, si son iguales disminuye num_letras en 1 y continua la iteración del ciclo `for`.